# Maximum length of K continuous subarrays of increasing sum

Tags: java, arrays

Divide an array into at least K continuous subarrays of increasing sum(sum of all elements of the current subarray is smaller or equal to next one . i.e. non-decreasing sum) such that the length of each subarray is at least L. Each element belongs to exactly one subarray. What is the max value of L such that all above-given conditions are fulfilled? value of L is always finite.

A = {3,2,2,4,2,3} K = 3
L must be 1 here as subarrays --> [[3],[2,2],[4,2,3]]

A = {3,2,1,4,2,3} K = 3
L must be 2 here as subarrays --> [[3,2],[1,4],[2,3]] all subarrays with non decreasing sum.

1<=k<=array.length()
1<=array.length()<=10^5

It's too hard for me to guess anything as there are too many conditions to be met.

Comment: hello, can somebody please help me?

Comment: [Read this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-the-given-array-into-k-sub-arrays-such-that-maximum-sum-of-all-sub-arrays-is-minimum/)

Comment: Sorry but I cannot relate the problem discussed in the article with this problem @AKAA